# Add option for administrator to submit link

Tags: theme-development

I created a theme, and the theme have social icons in the header, now i want a theme feature, where administrator can link their profile to social icons that I have on my theme. I researched on this, but am still clueless, till now I am just able to add theme option menu in Admin panel> appearance which have a text box for inserting social link. I am searching clue for grabbing the value of that textbox and add it in the anchor tag of social icon.

Any help

Comment: What is your question exactly? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Do not expect the work to be done for you. Please update your question with an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/189157/edit). See [ask].

Comment: I created a theme, and the theme have social icons in the header, now i want a theme feature, where administrator can link their profile to social icons that I have on my theme. I researched on this, but am still clueless, till now I am just able to add theme option menu in Admin panel> appearance which have a text box for inserting social link. I am searching clue for grabbing the value of that textbox and add it in the anchor tag of social icon @Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

If you have sucessfully added option field in Theme options; Now you just need to call it on front end. For that just use

```
    get_option( $option, $default );
```

For example if you are saving your social link with key "text_box_value", then you can simply call it in front end as following;

```
   <a href="<?php echo get_option( 'text_box_value' , '#' ); ?>" >Your Social icon</a>
```

In above example if your option field is empty this will echo "#" in href instead of leaving it empty.

For more on [get_option() visit Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create Theme options, here are some good example how to create theme options:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-options-panel/

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel--net-9360

After successfully create your theme options, you will be able to save your social links in Wp- Admin. Than you need to get your theme options and use them.
You can do by this:

```
get_option( $option, $default );
```

For example if you are saving your facebook link with key "text_facebook", then you can simply call it in front end as following;

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option( 'text_facebook' , '#' ); ?>" >Your facebook icon</a>
```